# PGDATA/base/XXXX is missing and pgsql_tmp is created automatically

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql, PGDATA/base/XXXX is missing (Some database named XXXX is missing). Also, PGDATA/base has another folder named pgsql_tmp which wasn't created by me.

- What would be the possible reasons for my database XXXX can get
  deleted ?
- Why the pgsql_tmp folder was created ? and it is empty.
- Is there any way that i can get my database back ?

Comment: there should not be the folder with dbname, but with oid - is it what you mean?..

Comment: Ya right. I meant the OID (eg: base\16385)

Answer (score 0):

`pgsql_tmp` is ok, that directory contains temporary data.

If the missing directory matches the `oid` of a database in `pg_database`, your database is irrevocably gone and you can only restore from a backup.

It could be an attack, operator error or a file system check that lost data (any crashes lately?).

Comment: Yes. The missing directory name (OID) matches with a database in pg_database.  is running a scan can cause this (antivirus scan)?

Comment: Look at the antivirus program's log. It is recommended to exclude the PostgreSQL data directory from antivirus programs, they are known to cause problems, e.g. with file locking.